# How to Create Multistore StoreAdmin User that manage only his Store in prestashop?

Tags: permissions, admin, prestashop-1.6, multistore

I already implemented/enabled Multistore functionality in my project but I don't know how to Create Multistore, StoreAdmin, User that manage only his store in PrestaShop?

I created one profile and try to give permission for only to manage this store but I don't find any store based permission in PrestaShop backoffice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop doesn't support this feature. To turn your Prestashop store into Prestashop marketplace multi vendor, you can refer this Prestashop Marketplace Builder module:

https://addons.prestashop.com/en/marketplace-creation/32443-marketplace-builder-multi-vendor.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, PrestaShop does not have this feature by default.

You have to search for additional module to improve access management.

MarketPlace modules usually have such a possibility.

https://addons.prestashop.com/en/marketplace-creation/8057-advanced-marketplace.html

https://addons.prestashop.com/en/marketplace-creation/21669-knowband-multi-vendor-marketplace.html

https://marketplace.webkul.com/add-ons/prestashop/

https://www.jose-aguilar.com/modulos-prestashop/en/36-ja-professional-marketplace.html